# When should I tap out?

Tags: americas-army-3

I know, that as long as I am down but not dead yet, I can whisper information to my teammates, but at the same time, I could be the fish bait.

What are the advantages and, more importantly, the disadvantages of tapping out when you are down?

Answer (score 1):

When this game first came out I was in a clan called Nuke[something...] and we had a Unit/Clan meeting to discuss this.  We found that it was best to remain alive as long as possible and provide intel rather than "tap out".  The consensus for the team was to proceed to your wounded teammate as slowly and cautiously as possible, even if that meant sacrificing your teammate for (possible) good intel.  I hope this helps!